# Chrome extensions - unable to load external scripts inside background.js

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, ethereum

I have a chrome extension. I'm unable to call an external script to deal with ethereum (web3.min.js) inside of background.js script. I get this error when trying to call the script:

```
    Uncaught EvalError: Refused to evaluate a string as JavaScript because 'unsafe-eval' is not an allowed source of script in the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' blob: filesystem:".
```

What I'ver tried so far:
 1. Downloadling the script to the extension folder, adding it to the manifest.json:

```
    "background":{"scripts":["web3.min.js", "background.js"]}
```

It includes it, but gives the same error inside of the included file, as it uses other libraries in turn.
2. Using XMLHttp request:

```
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("GET", "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/ethereum/web3.js@1.0.0-beta.34/dist/web3.min.js", true);
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
          var resp = eval("(" + xhr.responseText + ")");
      }
    }
    xhr.send();
```

3. Appending it to the dom

   ```
   var script = document.createElement("script");
   script.src = "./web3.min.js";
   document.head.appendChild(script);
   ```

None of these solutions worked for me. I understand that it's because of security reasons, but aren't there any solutions? I just want to include web3 in my extension.

Comment: Allowing external code to run in the highly privileged context of the background script is an absolutely terrible idea but if you insist you can [relax the default CSP](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy) although a better approach is to run it inside a [sandboxed iframe](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/sandboxingEval).

Comment: The first method should work if the library doesn't contain unpermitted calls like `eval(..)` or `new Function(..)`

Comment: The first method works as including it, but It gives the same error inside of the script, as it contains in turn other files. I updated the question

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should be able to use `web3.js` within your background script if you install the package and import the minified version that it comes with.

```
npm i --save web3
```

```
import Web3 from 'web3/dist/web3.min.js';
...
const web3 = new Web3(Web3.givenProvider || provider);
const contract = new web3.eth.Contract(abi, contractAddress);
```

If this still doesn't work, I think the `web.js` [project README](https://github.com/web3/web3.js#in-the-browser) has more details about troubleshooting.